# how to maintain curvature when using loop tools on a curved surface?

Tags: modeling, subdivision-surface, topology

Im trying to put a hole in a curved surface while maintaining curvature and clean topology. Deleting a vertex and selecting the loop and using loop tools > circle always flattens out the surrounding area and i can never get the curvature right when sliding edges and vertices around arbitrarily. [image]

Comment: moonboots to the rescue once again!

Answer (score 1):

Create another cylinder that has the same radius (or duplicate the current one and rotate it 90° on Z). Select your cylinder with the hole, select all the vertices around the hole, assign them to a vertex group (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

Give a *Shrinkwrap* modifier to the cylinder with the hole, choose the other one as *Target*, select the vertex group, apply the modifier:

[image]

You may need to give a *Subdivide Surface* modifier to the other cylinder if necessary.